# How to establish database connection from wordpress docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I try running a docker compose wordpress by using this guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

This is the yaml file as described in the guide:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DEBUG: "true"
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

After I run my

```
"docker-compose up -d"
```

command, I go to "http://localhost:8000/" in my browser and get the white page with "Error establishing a database connection". According to the guide, wordpress should show me the 5 minute Installation already at this point. When I run the container with wordpress debug true, this error message is shown then:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1612
```

Connection refused

I now use

```
docker exec it container_id /bin/bash
```

and type "mysql -p". Now I use the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD from the docker compose file but I get access denied ("Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

I am not sure what I did earlier, but at some point it worked and I listed the databases and the mysql.users and the db and user were there.

So I dont even know, what the problem here is...

And why can I not access as root anymore? Does anyone know what to do?

EDIT: changed port back to 3306, I tried 3308 just to see if that may be a port issue

Comment: I think you should use `db:3306` not `3308`.

Comment: Hey tgogos, I tried that already. Just checked if that is not a port issue.

Comment: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" would mean that you havent got the privilege to acces thru the local unix socker... Have you tried "mysql -p -h 127.0.0.1 ..." ?? That would show if you can acces thru tcp/ip on the local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another post and they used this yaml. Still not sure why this works, but it does.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - 8000:80
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs of a service. To check the services, do:

```bash
$ docker-compose logs
...
db_1 | 2022-10-21  2:08:08 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221021  2:08:08
db_1 | 2022-10-21  2:08:08 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1 | Version: '10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

For example, If you have a mariadb service named `db` and it doesn't print that way, you might have to wait for it to print.